# Want to display only those dates whose month is '10' using Mysql

Tags: mysql

I Have one column in the table called "date". In this column there are some dates stored from different months. I want to display only those dates whose month is '10'. How can we write query to print the desired output using substring() function of mysql ? Or else any other solution for this ?

[image]

O/p : first 8 records from this column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a lot of options for working with dates. In this case, combining the [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function with [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) would be easiest; `MONTH()` takes a date as input and returns the month number, starting at 1 for January, while `STR_TO_DATE()` will format your (non-standard) date string into a date MySQL understands.

Your query would then become:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y')) = 10;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but getting empty table entries.

Comment: @Rohit I didn't take into account that MySQL does not understand the date format you are using. Please see my editted query.

Comment: @JoryGeerts You can remove the `LIMIT 8`, The `first 8 records from this column only` was not a limitation, it was an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE_FORMAT then `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m')` to be able to get the value of month alone

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m') = '10'
```

Comment: @Rohit really? can I see that result?

Comment: @NewbeeDev why use the `LIMIT 8`? OP said that only the first 8 should pe printed because these are the ones which will pas the test. It wasn't a limitation it was an explanation of what should happen.

Comment: yes nick you are right i have tried the query provided by newbee without limit .. still it is showing empty result.

Answer (score 0):

select * from your_table where month(date) = 10;

Comment: thnx for the help

Comment: Please add a description of your code as to why it is the best answer. Also please format code appropriately.

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon thank you for your advice. I'm sorry... I'll do my best to comment... next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `date` FROM table_name
    WHERE MONTH(`date`) = '10'
    ORDER BY `date`   -- without this, the a random 8 would be delivered
    LIMIT 8
```

Comment: thnx for the help

Answer (score 0):

If date column is datetime or Time stamp then

```
SELECT `date` FROM `tablename` WHERE month(`date`) =10
```